# Crossfading songs when streaming to Icecast2 in Java

Tags: java, audio, streaming, icecast

Some months ago, I have written an own stream source client in Java for streaming playlists to your Icecast2 server.
The logic is simple:
You have multiple "Channels" and every channel has a playlist (in this case a folder filled with mp3 files). After a channel has started, it begins streaming by picking the first song and stream it via http to the icecast2 server. As you can imagine, after a song ended, the next one is picked.

Here is the code which I am currently using for sending audio to icecast:

https://gist.github.com/z3ttee/e40f89b80af16715efa427ace43ed0b4

What I would like to achieve is to implement a crossfade between two songs. So when a song ends, it should fade out and fade in the next one simultaneously.

I am relatively new when it comes to working with audio in java. What I know, that I have to rework the way the audio is sent to icecast. But there is the problem: I have no clue how to start or where to start.

If you have any idea where or how to start, feel free to share your experience.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think for cross-fading, you are likely going to have to use a library that works with the audio at the PCM level. If you wish to write your own mixer, the basic steps are as follows:

1. read the data via the input stream
2. using the audio format of stream, convert the audio to pcm
3. as pcm, the audio values can be mixed by simple addition -- so over the course of the cross fade, ramp one side up from zero and the other down to zero
4. convert the audio back to the original format and stream that

The cross fade that is linear, e.g., the audio data is multiplied by steps that progress linearly from 0 to 1 or vice versa (e.g., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...) will tend to leave the midpoint quieter than when running the beginning or ending track solo. A sine function is often used instead to keep the sum a steady volume.

There are two libraries I know of that might be helpful for mixing, but would likely require some modification. One is [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound), the other is [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue) (which I wrote). The modifications required for *AudioCue* might be relatively painless. The output of the mixer is enclosed in the class *AudioMixerPlayer*, a *runnable* that is located on line 268 of [AudioMixer.java](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adonax/audiocue/AudioMixer.java). A possible plan would be to modify the output line of this code, substituting your broadcast line for the *SourceDataLine*.

I should add, the songs to be played would first be loaded into the *AudioCue* class, which then exposes the capability of real-time volume control. But it might be necessary to tinker with the manner in which the volume commands are issued.

I'm really interested in having this work and could offer some assistance. I'm just now getting involved in projects with *Socket* and *SocketServer*, and would like to get some hands-on with streaming audio.